# Как защититься от большого кол-во запросов?

Tags: php, nginx, ddos

Проблема такая - php сьедает все ресурсы и уходит в глухой нокаут, когда QA начинает бомбить api большим кол-во запросов.

Распишу кейс чуть подробнее.
Есть api на php 8.0, там есть разные роуты, например:

GET /locales - получить поддерживаемые локали
GET /translations - получить переводы
GET /currencies - получить поддерживаемые валюты
POST /auth/signIn - авторизация

Когда QA начинает слать тонну запросов на GET роуты, сайт начинает тормозить, но сразу-же приходит в себя, когда запросы отключаются.

Я считаю такое поведение верным, так-как исходный сервер не слишком силен и такое поведение будет исправлено горизонтальным масштабированием.

Однако, если полетят запросы на логин, приложение уходит в глубокий нокаут, остановка запросов не спасает ситуацию. Даже спустя час, приложение со 100% перегрузом процессора не отвечает, хотя при этом docker контейнер с php не падает.

я вдоль и поперек перекопал signIn, это достаточно простой кейс, я не вижу того, чтобы могло приводить к таким печальным последствиям. Логика кейчас простая:

- ищем юзера в базе
- сравниваем пароли
- если пароль подходит, генерируем токен
- выдаем результат

всего происходит 7 запросов в базу (6 селектов и 1 инсерт), оптимизировать это некуда, база полупустая, этак записей 20 в общей сумме. Никаких слипов ничего, приложение работает корректно до момента бомбежки запросов.

Куда можно вообще копнуть по этому вопросу ?

nginx conf

```
limit_req_zone          $binary_remote_addr zone=wingames:10m rate=10r/m;
```

php conf

```
pm = static
pm.start_servers = 8
pm.max_children = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 12
pm.max_requests = 150
```

Comment: 100% длительная загрузка процессора самим приложением говорит, что в нем какой то бесконечный цикл образуется

Comment: похоже, но подобных циклов там нет, и если запросов не много (не тест, а живые люди тыкают) проблем не возникает

Comment: цикл может быть и не у вас в коде, а в какой нибудь из используемых библиотек и возникающий при каких то ошибках. Например по таймауту рвется соединение с БД и модуль работы с БД не может его восстановить и корректно отработать ошибку

Comment: Откуда у вас здесь образовалось 6 селектов? Чтобы узнать, есть ли пользователь в базе достаточно одного запроса

Comment: Я даже не уверен, что нужен отдельный select и отдельный insert, а нельзя все объединить в один insert..select

Comment: объединить не получится, по крайней мере не нарушая архитектуру приложения. это на разных слоях идет сбор данных для формирования ответа, сами запросы разруливает орм, я не думаю, что есть смысл вмешиваться в эти процессы. кол-во запросов закроется кешом.

Comment: А как дела на бд обстоят? Очередь запросов жива? Бд успевает отдать результат?

Comment: Так вы определитесь: вам нужно ускорить работу приложения или ничего не менять в приложении? Вам не приходило в голову, что сама архитектура может быть кривая?

Comment: с бд, все четко. тоесть приложение пустое, бд не грязная, запросы составлены четко.

Comment: на корявость архитектуры бы с виду не грешил, конечно все может быть, но сегодня тестировали все GET запросы, все работает как нужно, тоесть процессор в 100%, все лагает, но не падает. Завтра будем разбирать пост запросы. Пока топорным перебором роутов пытаемся понять в чем дело.

Comment: логируйте время старта каждого роута и время когда он отдает ответ - смотрите какой из них отрабатывает дольше всего. тоже самое сделайте с sql-запросами. у меня была похожая ситуация, когда отдельно все работало нормально, но вот в совокупности с несколькими запросами к нескольким роутам одновременно - система начинала тормозить - логирование помогло - нашли запросы которые именно при выполнении одновременно друг с другом давали проблемы.

Comment: Самый простой способ узнать где проблема, это профилирование.